# how to drag and drop in webdriverIO instead of using default function

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

trying to drag and drop an element. If I hold a cursor into an element then it shows hand cursor.

I tried following code -

```
var singleLine = await $("//p[contains(.,'Single-line Text')]/parent::div");
var dropzone = await $(".chakra-modal__body > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)");

await singleLine.dragAndDrop(dropzone, 5000);
```

Here is the screen-shot of the window I want to automate.
[need to drop the element in that area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2gOj.png)

I also tried alternative approach, but did not work, here is the code -

```
        try {
        await singleLine.dragAndDrop({x: 644, y: 305 });
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        }
        await dropzone.click();
```

this works only and only if I move the mouse in the automation window.
Point to be noted that this website is develop using REACT

Comment: Did you receive any error, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: no error, it just pass the line but do nothing

Comment: can you share any logs from the test run?

Comment: no error log found in the logs and I updated my questions